# Working with buttons in android

Tags: android, button, methods, onclick

Alright, so i've been making great progress on the app i'm trying to create, but most of the tutorials that i've been learning from only showcase the wondrous feature of having only one active widget inside the application at a time...

The thing is, my application requires 2 or more buttons and that's the part i'm partially stuck at. My code implements a "SetWordsBtn" shown below (everything else is declared),

> public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
>
> ```
>    super.onCreate(icicle);
>    setContentView(R.layout.main);
>
>    SetWordsBtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.SetWordsBtn);
>
>    SetWordsBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
> ```
>
> }

which implements a onClick() like this:

> public void onClick(View view) {
>
> ```
>   startWords();
> ```
>
> }

but what if i have another button that deletes the words such as "DelWordsBtn"? I was thinking i could declare both buttons simultaneously like this:

> ```
>   SetWordsBtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.SetWordsBtn);
>   DelWordsBtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.DelWordsBtn);
>
>   SetWordsBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
>   DelWordsBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
> ```

but what about the onClick() method? Does it automatically apply itself to both the buttons when i do this?

How am i able to declare a seperate onClick from each other so it both does different stuff when i click on either one of them?

I was thinking the answer could be something like this, but i dunno :

> ```
>   //Declarations
>   SetWordsBtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.SetWordsBtn);
>   DelWordsBtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.DelWordsBtn);
>
>   SetWordsBtn.setOnClickListener(setWordsView);
>   DelWordsBtn.setOnClickListener(delWordsView);
>
>   //onClick Functions
> ```
>
> public void onClick(View setWordsView) {
>
> ```
>   startWords();
> ```
>
> }
>
> public void onClick(View delWordsView) {
>
> ```
>   deleteWords();
> ```
>
> }

So it would actually link the startWords() function to the SetWordsBtn, and deleteWords() to DelWordsBtn...

Any clear cut explanation/form of help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance guys. :)

Comment: Are you asking how to declare individual onClick() methods for each of your Buttons?

Comment: yes. i'm following kcoppock's example but i'm still unsure where do i put that method in. Do i stuff the code into onCreate or outside of onCreate?

Comment: nevermind, i got the hang of it. thanks everyone! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The typical convention is to just switch off of the ID of the View that is clicked. For example:

```
View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()) {
            case R.id.SetWordsBtn:
                startWords();
                break;
            case R.id.DelWordsBtn:
                deleteWords();
                break;
        }
    }
};

int[] ids = { R.id.SetWordsBtn, R.id.DelWordsBtn };

for(int i : ids) ((Button)findViewById(i)).setOnClickListener(listener);
```

Comment: Hmm, so this helps create a case where the application finds what the person is clicking when he/she clicks on any button?

Comment: Yes. So you have only one listener this way, and you can assign it to any of your clickable views. The onClick method is passed the View which was clicked, and in your switch statement, you simply add logic for each View ID that you wish to handle. If there is no case statement for the View you clicked, nothing will happen.

Comment: oh. i see, wow, that's pretty efficient! thanks for the help!

Comment: The btn.setOnClickListener(new ...    uses an anonymous inner class to create a listener for each button, whereas you are allowing the class containing your buttons to handle the clicks...

Comment: hmm. does this mean it would be more memory consuming this way? im confused now after looking at joseph's answer :S

Comment: You're technically creating more listener objects with my method, so perhaps it is marginally less memory-efficient, but in the tiniest amounts that would almost certainly be non-noticable (unless you have zillions of buttons).  I'd go with whichever one seems easier to write.

Comment: Yeah, joseph's method is fine as well, and the difference is not significant memory-wise. The main issue is that with a lot of buttons, you'll be writing redundant code over and over again if you create an anonymous inner for each button. If you're just doing a couple, it's no big deal, but I always try to minimize repetition when possible.

Comment: And yeah, this would all go in onCreate(). Think of this as your initialization: before you allow interaction from the user, you need to use onCreate to initialize your click listeners and other logic.

Answer (score 1):

You can alternatively set up anonymous inner class(es) that listen, instead of having your Activity itself be the listener that implements OnClickListener.  Example from the Android Button javadoc:

```
     button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             // Perform action on click
         }
     });
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html

P.S. start your local variable names, and method names, with lower case letters -- upper case is for class names.

Comment: ah. so i could just keep declaring different functions for each different button?

by the way, this is supposed to be implemented inside onCreate, right?

P.P.S - i know my naming convention is kinda weird, thanks for the tip!

Comment: Yes to both questions.  Except you mean "different anonymous inner classes implementing onClick()" instead of "different functions" -- but that's just semantics ;^)

Answer (score 0):

Where you suggested:

```
public void onClick(View setWordsView) {

  startWords();
}

public void onClick(View delWordsView) {

  deleteWords();
}
```

If you think about it, there is no difference in the two method declarations and you would get a build error (method signatures are the same, even though the method parameter, View, has a different name).

If I understand your question correctly then the answer given by kcoppock is correct. You also could define an [Anonymous Class](http://geekexplains.blogspot.com/2008/06/local-and-anonymous-inner-classes-in.html)

Answer (score 0):

Drag and drop button on *graghiclayout.xml
...>right click the button -->choose other properties....>choose inherited from view ---->click on click ....name it callme*.

That will be shows like this:

**xml file**

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="76dp"
    android:layout_y="58dp"
    android:onClick="callme"
    android:text="Button" />
```

Run once your project:

*Open src --->activity .java
----->*, do the coding like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.main);

   but=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
}

public void callme(View v)
{
//Do somthing
}
```