# Why onClick wont fire if implemented through interface but works properly if attached on View individally

Tags: android

This LinearLayout is nested, it holds some info and when user clicks on it, it should fire up intent. Like the title says, one way works other does not. I'm a noob what I'm missing here? Also did I use descendantFocusability and clickable attributes properly?

View which is clicked:

```
          <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/left_drawer_seg1_location_info"
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="80"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="3dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Location:"
                    android:textSize="11sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/left_drawer_location_label"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Text" />
            </LinearLayout>
```

Method that works:

```
drawerLocationChange = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer_seg1_location_info);
    drawerLocationChange.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(new Intent(Home.this, SelectLocation.class));

        }
    });
```

Method that's not firing anything (interface is implemented):

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.left_drawer_seg1_location_info:
            startActivity(new Intent(Home.this, SelectLocation.class));
            Log.i("Click","Click");
            break;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Hi are you using both of them in single activity?

Comment: Both are in the same activity, but one is always commented out. Actually I tried with interface first, and when I saw it's not working I commented it out and did it by attaching method on view directly

Comment: possible duplicate of [Working with buttons in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506443/working-with-buttons-in-android)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must've forgot to use

```
drawerLocationChange.setOnClickListener(this);
```

when you're implementing the interface

Comment: Damn it. I did :( sorry guys

Comment: @MunezNS, it happens when you are in learning phase. Please accept this as correct answer. Glad to help

Answer (score 0):

If you automatically want a view to use its host Activitys onClick method, you must write `android:onClick="onClick"` in your xml layout.